# ASP .Net runat server controls not compiling

Tags: asp.net, servercontrols

I have created a new Web project (.Net 3.5) and I've removed the original `Default` page in favour of creating a `Master` page and then recreating a `Default` with `Master` page.  All worked lovely.  Now, when I add my controls inside of the `ContentPlaceHolder` on the `Default` page, I get compiler errors when I try to access the controls from the `CodeFile`:

> Error 4   '_Default' does not contain a
>   definition for 'FirstName' and no
>   extension method 'FirstName' accepting
>   a first argument of type '_Default'
>   could be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

My declaration of the control:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="FirstName" />
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Page declaration:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Master/MasterPage.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
```

Code-behind:

```
string firstname = FirstName.Text;
```

Comment: Perhaps a stack trace is in order?

Comment: Code-behind? We need to see the class declaration in the .aspx.cs as well as the @Page tag.

Comment: Also, what is "FirstName" embedded in?  Is there some other container (like a repeater or grid) that you have placed it into?  It might help if you put your entire default.aspx page in pastebin.com

Comment: Firstname is contained within a table, but this code is copied from another site I have made and its working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get this working by changing `CodeFile` to `CodeBehind`.

Working:

`<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Master/MasterPage.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>`

Not working:

`<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Master/MasterPage.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>`